# How do I use a new extended class instead of the original in another loaded class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I have a module in which I've defined a Graph class which uses another class, Vertex.

```
# Graph.py
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertList = {}
        self.numVertices = 0 

    def addVertex(self,key):
        self.numVertices += 1
        newVert = Vertex(key)
        self.vertList[key] = newVert
        return newVert

    def getVertex(self,k):
        if k in self.vertList:
            return self.vertList[k]
        else:
            return None

class Vertex(object):
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.id = key
        self.connectedTo = {}
```

I want to extend the Vertex class for use in another module:

```
# BFSGraph.py
from Graph import Vertex,Graph

class Vertex(Vertex):
    def __init__(self,key):
        super(Vertex,self).__init__(key)

        # extensions for BFS
        self.predecessor = None
        self.dist = 0 
        self.color = 'w' # white, grey, and black

class BFSGraph(Graph):
    def getColor(self,k):
        return self.getVertex(k).color

def test():
    g=BFSGraph()
    g.addVertex('a')
    g.getColor('a')
```

When I run the test routine it returns "'Vertex' object has no attribute 'color'", so the changes I've made to Vertex are not propagating down to Graph, and BFSGraph isn't using the extended Vertex.

How can I make Graph and BFSGraph use the new Vertex?

Comment: This `class Vertex(Vertex):` looks strange.

Comment: @LutzHorn It works though. It's unnecessarily confusing and non-descriptive, so I wouldn't call it good style, but it works.

Comment: Here this is a Graph of vertex since you have method addVertex, getVertex. So why don't you inherit Graph to Vertex : `class Graph(Vertex)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right thing to do is to allow your `Graph` class to take a user-defined class as an argument, and use that to represent vertices. Your `graph` module can provide a suitable default.

In `graph.py` (modules should begin with lowercase letters):

```
class Vertex(object):
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.id = key
        self.connectedTo = {}

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, vertexclass=Vertex):
        self.vertList = {}
        self.numVertices = 0 
        self.vertexclass = vertexclass

    def addVertex(self,key):
        self.numVertices += 1
        newVert = self.vertexclass(key)
        self.vertList[key] = newVert
        return newVert

    def getVertex(self,k):
        if k in self.vertList:
            return self.vertList[k]
        else:
            return None
```

The only change is that `Graph.__init__` has a parameter whose default value is the plain `Vertex` class, allowing you to pass a different class when you create the `Graph` instance. That class is saved, and you use that whenever `addVertex` is called to create a new vertex.

Then, in another module or script where you want to use a custom vertex class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import graph

class MyVertex(graph.Vertex):
    def __init__(self,key):
        super(Vertex,self).__init__(key)

        # extensions for BFS
        self.predecessor = None
        self.dist = 0 
        self.color = 'w' # white, grey, and black

class BFSGraph(Graph):

    def __init__(self):
        super(BFSGraph, self).__init__(MyVertex)

    def getColor(self,k):
        return self.getVertex(k).color


def test():
    g=BFSGraph()
    g.addVertex('a')
    g.getColor('a')
```

Your `BFSGraph.__init__`, when called, just calls its parent's `__init__` with the `graph.Vertex` subclass you want to use.

This is not the only way to organize the code, but the key to remember is that your `Graph` class (or any subclass derived from it) should document exactly the behavior the class implementing the vertex needs to implement.

Comment: I ended up renaming the new Vertex as BFSVertex and overriding addVertex in BFSGraph to explicitly use BFSVertex. Thanks for the tips guys!

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can't, without modifying the `Graph` and `BFSGraph` classes.  If `Graph` refers `Vertex`, it refers to `Vertex`, and you can't make it refer to anything else without actually changing the code of `Graph`.  That said, there are three ways to do something like this.

The simplest solution is to make a derived version of `Graph` that overrides `addVertex` so it uses your new `Vertex` subclass.  Then you use that new class instead of the original `Graph` and all is well.

The second, sneakier, and riskier approach is to monkeypatch it:

```
import graph
graph.Vertex = MyNewVertex
```

Now anything that tries to use the `Vertex` class in the `graph` module will actually use your class instead.  This is risky, though, since you never know what it will do to other code that thought it was using the original `Vertex`.  (It's still a good idea to name your class something different, otherwise it's going to be confusing to tell which one is being used.)  Also, it can silently fail to work if another class imported `Vertex` before your monkeypatch took effect.

If you're designing the whole codebase and you really need to do this a lot, the larger-scale solution is to parameterize the vertex as part of the class.  This makes it easier to write your own derived classes that interoperate with each other.  That is, you do something like:

```
class Graph(object):
    vertexClass = Vertex

    def addVertex(self, key):
        # ...
        newVert = self.vertexClass(key)
        # etc.

    # etc.
```

Then later if you need to you can do:

```
class MyVertex(Vertex):
     # blah

class MyGraph(Graph):
    vertexClass = MyVertex
```

The idea is that you use a class variable so that the Graph class knows what class to use for its vertices.  You can then easily make a derived class that just changes this variable, without having to rewrite all the actual method code (assuming you really did keep the API the same in your MyVertex class).  This adds a layer of indirection and may be a bit overkill for small projects, but if you have a lot of interdependent classes it can be useful to do this to have them explicitly keep track of how they need to use each other.

Answer (score 0):

The only part of `Graph` that explicitly refers to & relies on `Vertex` is `addVertex`, where it uses `Vertex`'s constructor to make an object that is then stuffed inside a dictionary.  I recommend changing `addVertex` so that it takes the `Vertex` object to add as an argument, thereby making the caller do the construction and letting them determine which class of `Vertex` to use, e.g.:

```
def addVertex(self, key, newVert):
    self.numVertices += 1
    self.vertList[key] = newVert
    return newVert
```

or, to cut down on redundant arguments, after a simple addition to `Vertex`:

```
def addVertex(self, newVert):
    self.numVertices += 1
    self.vertList[newVert.getKey()] = newVert
    return newVert
```